# Is it true that, as per Vastu ShAstra, the pujA room should only be placed on the ground floor and not on the upper floors?

Tags: puja, vastu-shastra

> The Puja Room should be in the Ground Floor and not in the Basement.
>   The Puja Room should **not be on the upper floors**:

This is what claims [this article](http://architectureideas.info/2009/01/vastu-shastra-guidelines-puja-room/). Now, i am not interested in the so-called scientific reasons they give along with as to why they think it should be like that.

On Astrojyoti.com too, [this article](http://www.astrojyoti.com/vastupoojaroom.htm) says the same:

> The place of worship should be on the ground floor **and not upstairs**.

**Question- Is it true that, as per Vastu ShAstra, the pujA room should only be placed on the ground floor and not on the upper floors?**

I'm also interested to know the reasons as to why it should be so. Now, if this is true, then that's a problem, because it's very common for many people these days to live in multi-storied flats.